# Deleting a card or reassigning to new account

Tags: balanced-payments

We are in development and are having issues with cards and accounts.  It appears that once a card is associated with an account, it's stuck there forever.

We have situations where clients create new accounts, especially in development :), and need a way to either delete cards and accounts or assign a card to a new account.

When using the test 4111... card in development as we try to develop and test out creating new accounts and such, we get errors like "card-already-funding-src: Card has already been associated with an account" since that test card is already in an account.

Comment: In development of what? On what operating system, in which programming language, what have you tried? Your question will probably be closed if you don't provide some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually got the answer direct from Balanced.  The key is creating the card.  You can use the same card number but you need to get a new URI for each card, then you can add it to a new account!  If you try to add the same card with the same uri, it will fail.